# What's the differences between "Is he taking part in the play?" and "Does he take part in the play?"

Tags: differences

I want to know the differences between "Is he taking part in the play?" and "Does he take part in the play?" Are they both grammatically correct? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They both work, in the right context.  I will give some appropriate context for them:

> Is he taking part in the play this year? *(this particular time)*
>
> Does he take part in the spring play every year? *(habitual)*